# Edit .vstemplate file of project before it is a template

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I'm trying to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) guide to create a project template in Visual Studio 2013.

At number 3 I go to ["How to: Substitute Parameters in a Template"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx) and at number 2 is the instruction "In the .vstemplate file for the template, locate the ProjectItem element that includes this file."

My problem is that I don't have a .vstemplate file until I've done step number 4 in the first guide, which is to actually create/export the project to a template.

Is there a .vstemplate file in every project and I'm just missing it, or are the instructions wrong? Should I edit the .vstemplate file after I've created the template?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are wrong. The correct process would be:

- Create a project, modify it to suit your needs
- Project -> Export template...
- Deselect *Automatically import the template into Visual Studio*
- Unzip the exported template, modify it to suit your needs (including the `.vstemplate` file)
- Rezip the template and share (or place into `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Templates\ProjectTemplates` (change `<version>` to year, e.g. 2022)